# interfacing MMA7361L with PIC ADC

Tags: pic, sensor, adc

I'm trying to interface an mma7361L accelerometer (on breakout board with caps) to the analog inputs of an 18f46k20.  According to the PIC datasheet, the Vmax input voltage is Vdd + 0.3 which means I have to get the signal between 0V - 3.6V.

I only need to measure the Z-axis and from what I can tell it produces 850mV/g but I don't know if that's centered at an already offset voltage, or at zero. Does anyone here have experience with this chip? If so, what kind of signal conditioning do you recommend if any?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't used the device. But I can answer one part of your question.

When you take a look at page 3 of the [datasheet](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/MMA7361L.pdf) under `Output Signal` you see a value for `Zero-g` thats typically 1.65 volts for VDD = 3.3V. Even more detail is given in footnote 5 on the same page:

> The device can measure both + and – acceleration. With no input
>   acceleration the output is at midsupply. For positive acceleration the
>   output will increase above VDD/2. For negative acceleration, the
>   output will decrease below VDD/2.

So yes, the output signals is centered.

Comment: Ha, it seems I posted my answer at the same time you added the quote from the datasheet too. Sorry, didn't mean to steal your answer.

Comment: @stevenvh - Np, yours is better anyway ... you got a colored picture in it ;)

Comment: And with a drop-shadow! :-)

Comment: Thanks to both.  That's what I thought but the language about the 0g detect, etc. had be wondering if sitting at rest was considered 0g or the more proper 1g.  page 6 regarding static acceleration says:  
    
>" * When positioned as shown, the Earth’s gravity will result in a positive 1g output"  

and the Z-axis appears to be near the upper rail at rest in that figure.  I'm confused about how this is helpful at all.  That's why I think I'm misunderstanding it.  If the chip is just sitting on the bench, is that 1 or 0g?  And is THAT value centered?  I would think 0g = freefall, and 1g=normal.

Comment: also, I'm seeing lots of high frequency noise on the output even with my battery power scope and the chip running on battery.  Should I run it though a unity buffer or sallen-key filter or something?

Comment: @Mark - IMO, 0g is free fall and 1g is when the device "is just sitting on the bench". Everything else doesn't make sense. When you rotate the device, so that the y-axis is showing up, I would expect it to show 1g on the y output and 0g on the z output.

Comment: @Mark - The description on the first page confirms that: `[...] 0g-Detect which detects linear freefall [...]`

Comment: @Mark - To answer you last question in the comment: 0g is centered (1.65V), see the figure on page 6. It even shows the voltages when it is "sitting on the bench" (x = 1.65V, y = 1.65V, z = 2.45V). Pretty obvious ...

Comment: @PetPaulsen I agree.  I think I've got it now: 0g=freefall @VDD/2. 1g=bench rest @ (((VDD/2)+0.8V)=2.45V).  +1g acceleration = 2.45V + 0.8V= ~3.25V

Answer (score 2):

Page 3 of the datasheet:

> The device can measure both + and – acceleration. With no input acceleration the output is at midsupply. For positive acceleration the output
>   will increase above VDD/2. For negative acceleration, the output will decrease below VDD/2.

[image]

It has to provide the offset, because acceleration can be positive or negative, and a 1 g negative acceleration would need a negative supply to get the -800 mV output. It's a lot cheaper to offset the output so that it's always positive, and subtract the offset again in software.

**Further reading**
[Implementing Auto-Zero Calibration Technique for Accelerometers](http://cache.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN3447.pdf), Freescale application note